# Jest coverage cannot find files

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I am having some issues with jest coverage reporter. I have a .NET solution with 2 project, the app and a test project. My src typescript files are in the app project and my test typescript files are in the test project. when setting up the project it doesn't collect the code coverage for the src files and doesn't find the files at all.

**Error**

```
PASS  TestScripts/ConfigHelper.test.ts
ConfigHelper
  √ Initialise returns a ConfigHelper (11 ms)
  √ Get Config returns correct config (2 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.262 s
Ran all test suites.
```

**Project Structure**

```
Project/
├─ Content/
│  ├─ Src/
│  │  ├─ Scripts/
│  │  │  ├─ Helpers/
│  │  │  │  ├─ ConfigHelper.ts
├─ package.json
TestProject/
├─ TestScripts/
│  ├─ ConfigHelper.test.ts
├─ package.json
```

**jest.config.ts**

```
export default {
  roots: [
      "../TestProject/TestScripts",
      "../Project/Content/Src/Scripts/",
  ],
  testMatch: [
      "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)",
  ],
  transform: {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ["./../Project/Content/Src/Scripts/**/*.ts"],
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  coverageProvider: "babel",
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project",
  "scripts": {
      "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
      "format": "prettier --write .",
      "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.ts --coverage --colors"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
      "@jest/globals": "^29.5.0",
      "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.53.0",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.53.0",
      "eslint": "^8.34.0",
      "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
      "jest": "^29.4.2",
      "jest-editor-support": "^31.0.1",
      "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
      "prettier": "^2.8.4",
      "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
      "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
      "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```